# Java mission control memory information for classes

Tags: java, memory, java-mission-control

In Java mission control we can see memory usage.
If we have many String objects, we can see many

```
char[]
```

but we also see `java.lang.String`

Arrays of chars are shown because internally String uses them, but what then does represent when [Mission Control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) shows `java.lang.String`?

example https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUSIQ.png

Comment: my current assumption - it's because char[] is a reference variable, therefore is not shown under String class itself

Comment: 1 instance of String contains 1 instance of char[]. You see both because Mission Control lists all instances of everything.

Comment: @Michael, what does String size show? is it primitives only which do seat in String?

Comment: It contains a primitive int (to memo the hashCode); that's 4 bytes per instance = 24K bytes. It contains a reference to the char[]. That's 8 bytes (on 64bit jvm) = 48K bytes. The rest, I suppose, might be the stuff related to object identity: the monitor lock, etc.